# A curiosity for congruent number elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have recently been perfoming a large number of computations on congruent number elliptic curves, using the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture to predict heights.

If $N=8M+7$ is squarefree, then we expect $E_N: y^2=x^3-N^2x$ and the 2-isogenous curve $F_N:v^2=u^3+4N^2u$ to have odd rank. For the curves with rank $1$, the projected height of the generator of $F_N$ is nearly always half that of the generator of $E_N$, and so would normally be easier to find.

The exceptions to this all have at least 3 odd prime factors. For those with exactly $3$ factors,
the differences between the primes are always a multiple of $4$.

Is this known? Is it obvious? If not, anybody explain it?

Answer (score 3):

This could not be a comment, so it is an answer.

I'm not sure i got correctly the message from the OP, but here is a statistics of the *heights* $h(F)=h(P(F_N))$, and $h(E)=h(P(E_N))$  of generators $P(F_N)$ for $F=F_N$ and $P(E_N)$ for $E=E_N$ in the cases where $h(F)<h(E)$. The table was generated using [sage](https://www.sagemath.org), and in the cases where the the rank could not be "easily computed" the case was skipped. So many "bigger heights" do not occur.

The list contains only found cases where the height $h(E)$ of the generator of $E(\Bbb Q)$ is smaller as the corresponding *height* $h(F)$. The quotient $h(F)/h(E)$ is two, shown in the last column.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|l||c|c||r|r|c|}
\hline
N & N & r_F & r_E & h(F) & h(E) & {\displaystyle \frac{h(F)}{h(E)}} \\\hline
1023 & 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 31 & 1 & 1 & 35.8473662698859 & 17.9236831349429 & 2 \\\hline
1239 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 59 & 1 & 1 & 26.0698475230467 & 13.0349237615233 & 2 \\\hline
1311 & 3 \cdot 19 \cdot 23 & 1 & 1 & 6.42070898244804 & 3.21035449122402 & 2 \\\hline
1351 & 7 \cdot 193 & 1 & 1 & 18.2620621894512 & 9.13103109472562 & 2 \\\hline
1407 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 67 & 1 & 1 & 42.3801890482000 & 21.1900945241000 & 2 \\\hline
1463 & 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 19 & 1 & 1 & 7.91240380926402 & 3.95620190463201 & 2 \\\hline
1551 & 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 47 & 1 & 1 & 20.9996584892411 & 10.4998292446205 & 2 \\\hline
1631 & 7 \cdot 233 & 1 & 1 & 10.2437432584114 & 5.12187162920569 & 2 \\\hline
1679 & 23 \cdot 73 & 1 & 1 & 18.0532459865845 & 9.02662299329226 & 2 \\\hline
1743 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 83 & 1 & 1 & 59.8793770087365 & 29.9396885043682 & 2 \\\hline
1751 & 17 \cdot 103 & 1 & 1 & 11.6822329722788 & 5.84111648613939 & 2 \\\hline
1767 & 3 \cdot 19 \cdot 31 & 1 & 1 & 45.8220501212261 & 22.9110250606130 & 2 \\\hline
1967 & 7 \cdot 281 & 1 & 1 & 38.3199662503416 & 19.1599831251708 & 2 \\\hline
2079 & 3^{3} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 & 1 & 1 & 4.33024941358404 & 2.16512470679202 & 2 \\\hline
2159 & 17 \cdot 127 & 1 & 1 & 20.1711247777071 & 10.0855623888536 & 2 \\\hline
2247 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 107 & 1 & 1 & 39.9265599852503 & 19.9632799926251 & 2 \\\hline
2343 & 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 71 & 1 & 1 & 30.7338660826787 & 15.3669330413393 & 2 \\\hline
2415 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 23 & 1 & 1 & 11.8334303474177 & 5.91671517370884 & 2 \\\hline
2567 & 17 \cdot 151 & 1 & 1 & 20.7548562007538 & 10.3774281003769 & 2 \\\hline
2607 & 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 79 & 1 & 1 & 29.6073197109170 & 14.8036598554585 & 2 \\\hline
2679 & 3 \cdot 19 \cdot 47 & 1 & 1 & 30.7125711747342 & 15.3562855873671 & 2 \\\hline
2751 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 131 & 1 & 1 & 16.7203012594042 & 8.36015062970211 & 2 \\\hline
2807 & 7 \cdot 401 & 1 & 1 & 38.0565222110109 & 19.0282611055054 & 2 \\\hline
2919 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 139 & 1 & 1 & 28.5411837845288 & 14.2705918922644 & 2 \\\hline
2967 & 3 \cdot 23 \cdot 43 & 1 & 1 & 50.6070151369618 & 25.3035075684809 & 2 \\\hline
3007 & 31 \cdot 97 & 1 & 1 & 22.5050216483494 & 11.2525108241747 & 2 \\\hline
3135 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot 19 & 1 & 1 & 5.63906129855214 & 2.81953064927607 & 2 \\\hline
3143 & 7 \cdot 449 & 1 & 1 & 61.2195290884721 & 30.6097645442361 & 2 \\\hline
3247 & 17 \cdot 191 & 1 & 1 & 30.6211232160319 & 15.3105616080159 & 2 \\\hline
3255 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 31 & 1 & 1 & 6.98070877502530 & 3.49035438751265 & 2 \\\hline
3311 & 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 43 & 1 & 1 & 44.7522224043655 & 22.3761112021827 & 2 \\\hline
3399 & 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 103 & 1 & 1 & 29.4291953315624 & 14.7145976657812 & 2 \\\hline
3423 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 163 & 1 & 1 & 52.8327239021380 & 26.4163619510690 & 2 \\\hline
3591 & 3^{3} \cdot 7 \cdot 19 & 1 & 1 & 8.95022228245589 & 4.47511114122794 & 2 \\\hline
3759 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 179 & 1 & 1 & 27.1627711409189 & 13.5813855704595 & 2 \\\hline
3791 & 17 \cdot 223 & 1 & 1 & 21.6038597996372 & 10.8019298998186 & 2 \\\hline
3927 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 17 & 1 & 1 & 25.7423670140126 & 12.8711835070063 & 2 \\\hline
3999 & 3 \cdot 31 \cdot 43 & 1 & 1 & 25.1390502760760 & 12.5695251380380 & 2 \\\hline
4047 & 3 \cdot 19 \cdot 71 & 1 & 1 & 59.5381153041493 & 29.7690576520746 & 2 \\\hline
4063 & 17 \cdot 239 & 1 & 1 & 33.6201733123958 & 16.8100866561979 & 2 \\\hline
4071 & 3 \cdot 23 \cdot 59 & 1 & 1 & 32.3583960441806 & 16.1791980220903 & 2 \\\hline
4183 & 47 \cdot 89 & 1 & 1 & 63.1797865950490 & 31.5898932975245 & 2 \\\hline
4191 & 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 127 & 1 & 1 & 44.2977627337341 & 22.1488813668671 & 2 \\\hline
4319 & 7 \cdot 617 & 1 & 1 & 13.3164886659964 & 6.65824433299818 & 2 \\\hline
4431 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 211 & 1 & 1 & 13.4795492212960 & 6.73977461064800 & 2 \\\hline
4439 & 23 \cdot 193 & 1 & 1 & 25.2379598322772 & 12.6189799161386 & 2 \\\hline
4471 & 17 \cdot 263 & 1 & 1 & 29.1293039942451 & 14.5646519971226 & 2 \\\hline
4487 & 7 \cdot 641 & 1 & 1 & 39.3379697871404 & 19.6689848935702 & 2 \\\hline
4503 & 3 \cdot 19 \cdot 79 & 1 & 1 & 51.3601232550635 & 25.6800616275318 & 2 \\\hline
4543 & 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 59 & 1 & 1 & 82.5900881429937 & 41.2950440714969 & 2 \\\hline
4559 & 47 \cdot 97 & 1 & 1 & 29.6479192329371 & 14.8239596164685 & 2 \\\hline
4607 & 17 \cdot 271 & 1 & 1 & 17.2922821771960 & 8.64614108859801 & 2 \\\hline
4623 & 3 \cdot 23 \cdot 67 & 1 & 1 & 73.9689543233940 & 36.9844771616970 & 2 \\\hline
4711 & 7 \cdot 673 & 1 & 1 & 25.5153821122245 & 12.7576910561122 & 2 \\\hline
4767 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 227 & 1 & 1 & 84.7781303084486 & 42.3890651542243 & 2 \\\hline
4807 & 11 \cdot 19 \cdot 23 & 1 & 1 & 74.4648233907134 & 37.2324116953567 & 2 \\\hline
4935 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 47 & 1 & 1 & 7.13641666234485 & 3.56820833117243 & 2 \\\hline
4983 & 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 151 & 1 & 1 & 78.8704905412520 & 39.4352452706260 & 2 \\\hline
5159 & 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 67 & 1 & 1 & 21.7345051397385 & 10.8672525698693 & 2 \\\hline
5183 & 71 \cdot 73 & 1 & 1 & 83.4770516835033 & 41.7385258417516 & 2 \\\hline
5271 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 251 & 1 & 1 & 36.9683989599999 & 18.4841994800000 & 2 \\\hline
5359 & 23 \cdot 233 & 1 & 1 & 25.2609677731502 & 12.6304838865751 & 2 \\\hline
5487 & 3 \cdot 31 \cdot 59 & 1 & 1 & 52.1715444480934 & 26.0857722240467 & 2 \\\hline
5511 & 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 167 & 1 & 1 & 37.1021207472074 & 18.5510603736037 & 2 \\\hline
5719 & 7 \cdot 19 \cdot 43 & 1 & 1 & 10.9849752965575 & 5.49248764827874 & 2 \\\hline
5727 & 3 \cdot 23 \cdot 83 & 1 & 1 & 49.3970928745805 & 24.6985464372902 & 2 \\\hline
5767 & 73 \cdot 79 & 1 & 1 & 51.2908998150279 & 25.6454499075139 & 2 \\\hline
5775 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 & 1 & 1 & 4.33024941358404 & 2.16512470679202 & 2 \\\hline
5871 & 3 \cdot 19 \cdot 103 & 1 & 1 & 8.95074847677046 & 4.47537423838523 & 2 \\\hline
5943 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 283 & 1 & 1 & 95.4948577152046 & 47.7474288576023 & 2 \\\hline
5983 & 31 \cdot 193 & 1 & 1 & 82.3684742087008 & 41.1842371043504 & 2 \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
(The search was done for $N$ in the range $1000\le N\le 6000$.)

There are some cases with $N$ having two or four prime divisors.
Some other patterns using bigger $N$ values:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|l||c|c||r|r|c|}
\hline
N & N & r_F & r_E & h(F) & h(E) & {\displaystyle \frac{h(F)}{h(E)}} \\\hline
1000167 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 97 \cdot 491 & 1 & 1 & 35.1072424051541 & 17.5536212025771 & 2 \\\hline
1000239 & 3 \cdot 29 \cdot 11497 & 1 & 1 & 18.0349083276430 & 9.01745416382151 & 2 \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

In the last case, the situation is as follows.
We have $N=1000239 = 3 \cdot 29 \cdot 11497$. (The difference $29-3$ is not a multiple of four.) The $2$-isogenies between $E_N$ and $F_N$ map the generators as follows:

```
sage: N = 1000239
sage: EN, FN = EllipticCurve([-N^2, 0]), EllipticCurve([4*N^2, 0])
sage: PEN, PFN = EN.gens()[0], FN.gens()[0]

sage: PEN.xy()
(-5569330752/5929, -152072664682392/456533)
sage: PFN.xy()
(47717344249/379456, -166145928464553715/233744896)

sage: factor(5929), factor(379456)
(7^2 * 11^2, 2^6 * 7^2 * 11^2)

sage: phi_EF(PEN)
(47717344249/379456 : -166145928464553715/233744896 : 1)
sage: phi_EF(PEN) == PFN
True
```

So the isogeny from $E_N$ to $F_N$ of degree two maps the generator $P(E_N)$ into the other generator, $P(E_N)\to P(F_N)$. And if we try to go the other way $P(F_N)\to 2P(E_N)$.

```
sage: FN.isogeny(FN.torsion_points())
Isogeny of degree 2
    from Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 4001912228484*x over Rational Field
    to   Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 16007648913936*x over Rational Field

sage: FN.isogeny(FN.torsion_points())(PFN)
(4376572011592225/136983616 : 287255842000594605842255/1603256241664 : 1)
sage: 2*PEN
(4376572011592225/547934464 : 287255842000594605842255/12826049933312 : 1)
```

(The codomain of the above isogeny constructed by declaring the kernel $F_N[2]$, is not exactly $E_N$, but an isomorphich curve, and

```
sage: (2*PEN).height()
36.0698166552861
sage: FN.isogeny(FN.torsion_points())(PFN).height()
36.0698166552861
```

the corresponding heights are equal.)